# Need to update 1500 rows of Excel from an external site

Tags: python, excel, screen-scraping

I got tasked with checking our organizations internal phone book, which is roughly 1500 rows in excel; I'm supposed to check them against a newer, online internal phone book. (We're using Excel 2007, btw.)

In excel there is 1st column with the phone number and 2nd column with a name. I'd like to figure out a way to query the online phone book with the data from the 1st column and get the content of  to the 2nd column and continue till there are no more new rows.

The online phone book has the following url structure `https://ourinternalphonebook.com/#search/name_[QUERY]`
which might be useful.

The internal phone book also uses cookies for authentication.

The service we use for our phone book is bought from an external company, so I don't have access to the "raw data".

I don't think this can be achieved with excel alone, but I've been Googling around for a few days and python seems to be the best choice.

The problem is; I have no idea how python works. I've read tutorials here and there, but none of them have been any help. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Comment: Have you considered hiring somebody?

Comment: That's not really an option. I'm an unpaid intern (doing my mandatory, non-military service) so I'm the one everyone gives tasks like this. Also there is some confidential info in there, as we are a government organization. I guess I'm stuck doing it manually. Thanks for your suggestion! :)

Comment: You're stuck learning python manually? That's a nonsense sentence. You should suggest to your superior that the task be reassigned to somebody with programming experience. Also, there's no compelling reason to use python over any other scripting language.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'm stuck manually entering the numbers to the online phone book and checking against it :) I'll have a chat with my superior and see what we can come up with.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, Python is probably a reasonably good choice for this task, but in order to help you, we would need a lot more information (for example, what is the raw data returned by a call to the online phonebook?).

Do you have any programming experience? If you have no programming experience whatsoever, it might be hard to lead you in the right direction until you gain more.